# Can not solve R cannot be resolved to a variable issue

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I added the code for Android GCM service to an existing code, which is working perfectly before that. Then i found the error "R cannot be resolved to a variable". I build the project after clean it. But it is still not working. There is no errors showing in layout files or other xml files.

Could you please provide me with some ideas to solve this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Close and reopen the project, Also try relaunching eclipse. Check the "Problems" tab on eclipse. That generally has errors that sometimes are not shown elsewhere.

Comment: @Siddharth: The Problems tab only showing list of errors. That all are the same "R cannot be resolved to a variable"...

Comment: Double click on the error. It should point to some code. Check it.

Comment: You have some errors in your xml files. Re-check them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete R.java file from your source folder. Now Clean your project

and also try this.

Right Click on your **Projectname** >> **Android Tools** >> **Fix project Property**

Answer (score 1):

What is the api level that you are supporting? If its below 8 then try to look into the menu xml and delete `android:showasAction` field. When R.java is not created its always some error in  xml files. So also look into the `androidmanifest` file and styles xml. Basically search every xml for error according to your minimum api.

EDIT: Make sure you haven't imported android.R by any chance.If it is there delete it and then try all the answers till now.

Answer (score 1):

Try these

1. Close the project, Exit Eclipse, Reopen eclipse and Clean the project
2. In the Problems tab, select all errors and delete it. Clean the project one more time.
3. If you are using ubuntu, run a `chmod 777 <project folder>`
4. Delete the bin folder from file explorer

Let me know which worked.